# Use of json_object_put() in C library

Tags: c, linux, json-c

I am using the json-c in my C program (not C++). I am getting segfaults from time to time and trying to debug. To be honest, I might not have the full understanding how the library works so I am looking for any advice.

This is partially how I am using:

```
char* createjsonstatusstring()
{
json_object     *jsonmain,
                *jsontmp;
const char      *conststring;
char            *string;

jsonmain = json_object_new_object();
jsontmp = json_object_new_object();
json_object_object_add(jsontmp,"test",json_object_new_string("Beispiel"));
json_object_object_add(jsontmp,"test2",json_object_new_string("Beispiel2"));
json_object_object_add(jsonmain,"Data",jsontmp);

conststring = json_object_to_json_string_ext(jsonmain,JSON_C_TO_STRING_SPACED | JSON_C_TO_STRING_PRETTY); 
json_object_put(jsontmp);
json_object_put(jsonmain);

string = malloc(strlen(conststring)+1);
strcpy(string,conststring);
return string;
}
```

When doing the last `json_object_put` I am getting the segfault.
Can you explain why and how to improve?

Thanks!

/KNEBB

Comment: Why are you using `json_object_new_array`? Arrays are indexed with numbers, not with string keys. You use `json_object_array_add` with `json_object_new_array` and `json_object_object_add` with `json_object_new_object`.

Comment: You are right. Fixed it. Indeed I am using _new_object...

Comment: `string = malloc(strlen(conststring)+1);
strcpy(string,conststring);`?  Just use `strdup()`. Some heads may explode, but `strdup()` **will** be [standard in C23](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#7.26.2.6)  Of course, come 2050 or so, Microsoft will be bragging about how they're *working* to *become* somewhat *less* C23 non-compliant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#a04448b1c63173e1bfe49965835732075 :

```
void json_object_object_add     (   struct json_object *    obj,
        const char *    key,
        struct json_object *    val  
    )   

Upon calling this, the ownership of val transfers to obj. [..]
```

and

```
void json_object_put    (   struct json_object *    obj      )      

Decrement the reference count of json_object and free if it reaches zero. You must have ownership of obj prior to doing this or you will cause an imbalance in the reference count.
```

You do not have ownership in `jsontmp`, so doing `json_object_put(jsontmp);` is invalid. Just only call `json_object_put(jsonmain);`, `jsonmain` has ownership of `jsontmp`.